# Distributed C++ Application using message passing

Tags: c++, distributed-computing

I am working on DMTCP (http://dmtcp.sourceforge.net/) and am looking into developing an application which works across multiple remote machines and computes a result through messages. For example to calculate Fibonacci sequence for 3 machines A,B,C

1. A computes a starting number and sends that result to B
2. B takes A's results and uses that to compute next number and sends it to C.
3. C then computes the next number and sends to A and so on.

I am trying to build such an application such that I can checkpoint it to restart from failure. I was, however, unable to envision the code for such application. This is my first time working on any distributed application.

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Thank you :)

UPDATE: As suggested, my machine is not a cluster but I have multiple machines with their individual OS's connected via LAN to each other. My main objective is to run instances of my program on multiple machines such that they can communicate as shown above.

I hope this clears the question a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your machine is a cluster, you should be using MPI (Message Passing Interface). It offers a rich set of communication primitives, and is the parallelization workhorse in high performance computing.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting MPI. Open MPI looks quite interesting in this regards. However, I haven't quite encountered any sample MPI C++ code for remote serialized distributed application as I have explained above. Can you please point to me a similar example in MPI where such an application have been implemented. Also, what tutorials can I follow to develop such an application.

Comment: If your machine is not already a cluster, you can either install the necessary software to make it into a cluster, or you have to do without MPI. The main software component that's needed for a cluster, is a job scheduler like SLURM. Once you have a job scheduler installed, you need to configure it so that it knows what different servers belong to the cluster. This is purely a one-time, administrative task. Unfortunately, I don't know the details of this, as I've never set up a cluster myself. Once the cluster is set up, you just make a job allocation and use `mpiexec` to start your app.

Comment: Regarding MPI documentation: MPI is a standard which is available online (http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report.pdf). It defines bindings for C and fortran (yes, fortran is still quite big in high performance computing, unfortunately), but not for C++. The reason for the omission of C++ bindings is that you can simply use the C interface from a C++ program. You can find an introduction of how to use MPI here (https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/), it also includes example code in C and fortran (no C++, the C++ code would be almost identical to the C code).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lot of options, I'm currently working on a project with [ZeroMq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98MQ) and it can do the job just fine, so would any [other message queue software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue). You can also try some grid framework (IceGrid comes to mind), but that would most likely be an overkill.

For ZeroMQ see push/pull + maybe routers... The advantage is that "ØMQ system can run without a dedicated message broker". The disadvantage is that you'll have to come up with serialization/deserialization of the data (ØMQ does not provide one, which is not that bad).

Another option is the google's [Protocol Buffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers). Here you'll have integrated client/server and serialization/deserialization, but you'll have to learn new meta language to define the messages. They are quite flexible - versioning, backwards compatability... bit it's a bit heavy.